# A href intent link (launch android app) not working by JQuery

Tags: android, jquery, android-intent, hyperlink, location-href

I have strange problem. I want to launch my custom android app from my web app on browser.
I have followed the article here http://androidsrc.net/launch-android-application-from-browser-using-uri/. And it worked, I successfully trigger my app when web app user will click on link.
The problem is that I want to trigger it from js code behind.

here is the link:

```
<a id="launchLocationService" href="intent:#Intent;action=com.portacapena.theseusservicefrombrowser;category=android.intent.category.DEFAULT;category=android.intent.category.BROWSABLE;S.msg_from_browser=Launch;end">@Resources.GlobalResources.LaunchService</a>
```

I have tried jquery

```
$('#launchLocationService').click();
$('#launchLocationService')[0].click();
$('#launchLocationService').get(0).click();
```

and

```
    $("#launchLocationService").on("click", function () {
        alert();
    });
```

alert triggered but app not.

when I replace window.location or window.location.href the behaviour is unexpected, it s triggering when user navigates another link.

```
var clickTarget = document.getElementById("launchLocationService");
            var fakeMouseEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            fakeMouseEvent.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 20, 10, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

            clickTarget.dispatchEvent(fakeMouseEvent);
```

This monster piece of code is also not working.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance